# Buffer Overflow Padding?

Tags: assembly, stack, buffer, overflow, frame

I'm practicing on really basic buffer overflows and I noticed something strange.

My payload is like this:

```
[JUNKBYTES]+[EIP(jmp esp)]+[SHELLCODE]
```

Now, the "flow" of the application goes to EIP I specified in the exploit, then it should jump to the start of `[SHELLCODE]`, but it starts at the 5th byte of `[SHELLCODE]` - the first 4 bytes of `[SHELLCODE]` are like ignored.
I solved that modifying my payload with:

```
[JUNKBYTES]+[EIP(jmp esp)]+[PADDING(4 bytes)]+[SHELLCODE]
```

But ofcourse I want to understand why that happens. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Pretty good question, but it would be recommended to go back and *accept* the best answers to most or all of your earlier questions before proceeding with this one.

Comment: I accepted best answers of my earlier questions. Now please don't go offtopic.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by [EIP(jmp esp)]? `jmp esp` takes two bytes, is that what you have?

Comment: [EIP(jmp esp)] means that I overflowed EIP with a pointer to "JMP ESP". (so briefly an address that contains instruction "jmp esp")